# How to store any type of file in pouch db using ionic 4?

Tags: base64, ionic4, pouchdb

this is how I try it

```
await this.base64.encodeFile(uri).then((base64File: string) => {
      console.log(base64File);
      base64_data = base64File
      alert(JSON.stringify(base64_data));
      console.log(base64_data);
    }, (err) => {
      console.log(err);
      alert(JSON.stringify(err));
    });

this.db.putAttachment(att_id,att_name,base64_data, att_file_type).then(function (result) {
  console.log(result);
  alert(JSON.stringify(result)); 
}).catch(function (err) {
  // ouch, an error
  console.log(err);
  alert(JSON.stringify(err));
});
```

it works on image file but it return "" for pdf files

Answer (score 0):

### you can convert file data to binary data or base64

### this example convert to binary data

- first download file with XHR request can use jquery ajax , axios or ...
- set `responseType: 'arraybuffer'`
- after download or before download create document in pouch db

```
    axios.get(url, {
                    progress: false, responseType: 'arraybuffer',
                    onDownloadProgress: (progressEvent) => {
                        precent = (100 * progressEvent.loaded / progressEvent.total)
                        console.log(precent)
                    }
                })
.then(resp => {

                    //get db
                    let db = $db.dbModel

                    //set attach
                    db.get(doc._id).then((doc) => {

                        db.putAttachment(doc._id, 'index.mp4', doc._rev, new Blob([new Uint8Array(resp.data)], {type: 'video/mp4'}), 'video/mp4')
                            .then(res => {
                                // console.log('success store file')
                            })
                    })

                })
```

https://github.com/mohammadnazari110/pwa_offline_video_download